# "Do It Without Dues"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Recently reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/bernie-sanders-rips-jeff-bezos-210126465.html), there is a line, By the CEO of Amazon,

> "The unionization push being voted on at Amazon's Bessemer fulfillment center has been the focal point of a high-profile labor dispute between the behemoth "everything store" and the Retail, Wholesale, and Department Store Union. Amazon has aggressively pushed its workers to vote against unionization, launching a campaign called "**Do It Without Dues**" to encourage workers to stick to the status quo.

Does here, "due" mean the payment to the Union?

And please let me know what that means.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Every member of a trade union pays "union dues". This money pays for the union's organization: its office, officials, legal team etc. So Amazon are trying to deter their workers from forming a union by reminding them they'll have to pay their dues.

Comment: Amazon hopes to persuade the workers that payment of union membership subscriptions ('union dues') will gain them nothing that they cannot get by remaining as they are. Needless to say, this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Voting to close as this could be answered with a dictionary, or a cursory Google search of "union dues" at the least.

Comment: Note that **dues** is an uncountable noun - there is no singular form **due**.

Comment: @CanadianYankee If we use the word as "fee, charge", then it seems there is no singular form as you say. Thanks.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - we say 'give him his due'.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But as Canadian Yankee says, in the context of union membership we use the plural "dues".

Every member of a trade union pays "union dues". This money pays for the union's organization: its office, officials, legal team etc. So Amazon are trying to deter their workers from forming a union by reminding them they'll have to pay their dues and (as Michael Harvey says) by persuading them that union membership will gain them nothing that they can't get by remaining as they are. A matter of opinion, as that wise old owl says.

According to Etymonline the noun [dues](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=dues) came from the adjective [due](https://www.etymonline.com/word/due#etymonline_v_54140) from the Old French *deu*, past participle of *devoir* "to owe," from Latin *debere* "to owe."